# How to add one more action to the open cart registration page?

Tags: opencart

Let's say that I have the following simple form:

```
<html>
    <form action="register_bg.php" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="owner_id" value = "395060601"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="key_id" value = "3"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="f" value = "1043"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="optin" value = "y"/>
        Name: <input type="text" name="inp_1" />
        Lname: <input type="text" name="inp_2" />
        Email: <input type="email" name="inp_3" />
        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

How can I add this form and it's action to open cart registration page. i.e. the process should be as follows:

In opencart --> you will go to Account --> register --> fill up your details --> click the submit button.

So show can I take the fields values from registration page and edit the action file/class of open cart so I can post those values to my database?

Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks, 
Laith

Answer (score 1):

Under the Sales Menu, go to Customers -> Custom Fields. Here you can add custom fields for registration by selecting the custom field location as account